# Range in Python

Tags: python

I want to list numbers in range and I want to find out the amount of numbers in range.

For Example:

```
X = (5,6,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Y = (5, 5, 5,5 5,5 5,5 5)
range(X) # Want to know how many numbers in X.
```

If you guys could help it would be great.

Comment: unique numbers or just 'how many items in the list'?

Comment: You are asking how to find the number of elements of an integer array which are within some range(x,y) such that x <= i <= y, correct?

Comment: Please read the documentation.  The range function creates a generator which returns a group of numbers.

Comment: @tbilisidavid Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure you accept an answer by clicking the checkbox next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
X = (5,6,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
range = max(X) - min(X)
```

Comment: X has 7 different numbers, but max(X)-min(x) equals to 6: is 6 the correct value wanted for range ? what does mean _range_ here ?

Comment: @eyquem Range typically means the size of the interval between the smallest and largest elements.

Comment: And what is the size of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ?

Comment: The size of the interval between 1 and 7 is six.

Comment: A size measures something. The only thing I see than can be measured as 6 in X is the number of intervals between two succesive integers, that is to say 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->6, 6->7. Personally, I find weird to call range==size of a sequence the width of the interval separating the maximum element from the minimum elemnt. - Anyway, even if range == size would have this meaning, ``max(X) - min(X)`` isn't the correct answer since the OP asked for _"range(X) # Want to know how many numbers in X."_ and didn't speak of an interval

Comment: OK, thank you. It's a common sense of 'range' in statistic science. I hadn't this notion well known, english isn't my natural language. OK: range of X = (5,6,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) is effectively max(X)-min(X) ; however, the OP wanted the AMOUNT of numbers and that's not the range.

Answer (score 10):

Given the tuple or list X:

```
>>> X = (5,6,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
>>> X
(5, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

You find the number of elements with the [len](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) function:

```
>>> len(X)
10
```

If you want to find the number of unique elements, create a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) and look at its length:

```
>>> set(X)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> len(set(X))
7
```

The range (defined mathematically) of the set of numbers can be found with the [max](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) and [min](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) functions:

```
>>> (min(X), max(X))
(1, 7)
>>> max(X) - min(X)
6
```

Comment: great Thanks, i figured out it was len, but I forgot about set, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`filter(function, sequence)` returns a sequence consisting of those items from the sequence for which `function(item)` is true.

So you can do `filter(range(2, 10).__contains__, x)`, which will return the elements in `x` which are in `range(2, 10)`.

If you want to narrow this down to unique elements, call `set`:

```
set(filter(range(2, 10).__contains__, x))
```

Finally, if you want the number of these elements, simply call `len`:

```
len(filter(range(2, 10).__contains__, x))
```

this will return the number of elements in array `x` which are in range 2 to 10.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything close to what you say it does. Do you mean `filter(range(2, 10).__contains__, x)`? I've edited assuming that.

Comment: It's overcomplicated while ``[x for x in sequence if 2<=x<10]`` or ``set(y for y in sequence if 2<=y<10)`` do the job

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the number of numbers in X is the length of X:

```
len(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you want, but to get the mathematical range:

`max(X) - min(X)`

Were `max()` gets the highest value and `min()` gets the lowest one.